# Behavior of subsetting data frame for unique column values

Tags: r, dataframe

Background: I have a data frame with one column having duplicate values. I am trying to split this data frame by picking out all the rows with duplicate column values, process them and then spit out a new data frame with all processed rows.

I am amazed as to what is going wrong here in the following code:

```
    dataSet <- structure(list(DAY = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Tuesday", 
    "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
    "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
    "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
    "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
    "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
    "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday"), class = "factor"), 
        variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L), .Label = c("act1", "act2", "act3", "act4", 
        "act5", "act12", "act19", "act116", "act22", 
        "act6", "act13", "act111", "act117", "act23", 
        "act7", "act14", "act112", "act118", "act24", 
        "act8", "act15", "act113", "act119", "act25", 
        "act9", "act16", "act114", "act20", "act26", 
        "act10", "act17", "act115", "act21", "act27", 
        "act11", "act18"), class = "factor"), value = c(67, 
        65, 40, 79, 106, 90, 57, 59, 2, 12)), .Names = c("DAY", 
    "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


uniq <- unique(dataSet$variable)
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
     rowsPerVal <- dataSet[dataSet$variable == uniq[i], ]
     print(length(rowsPerVal))
}
```

I just don't understand how the final print statement says the length is 3, when there are 10 records in the data frame with the same value for `variable` column.

Comment: The `length` of a data frame is the number of columns, since it is in fact a list. You probably meant `nrow` or something.

Comment: Um, you only have one value in "uniq" in your example. Is that enough to illustrate your problem? Oh, never mind, joran's right: `print(nrow(...))` instead. Or better, just `print(sum(dataSet$variable == uniq[i]))` and skip the line above. There's certainly a way to do this without looping, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plyr` is also good for this split-apply-combine problem (split data set up into chunks, operate on each one, and put back together).

```
library("plyr")
ddply(dataSet, .(variable), nrow)
```

As others have said the `length()` of a `data.frame` is the number of columns; `nrow()` is the number of rows.

```
> ddply(dataSet, .(variable), nrow)
  variable V1
1     act1 10
```

You can replace `nrow` with an (anonymous) function which does whatever processing you want.

Answer (score 1):

`duplicated` returns TRUE only for the 2+th entry.  So you can use it to index your rows:

```
dataSet[duplicated(dataSet$variable),]
```

You can also assign to them:

```
dataSet[duplicated(dataSet$variable),]$value <- NA 
> dataSet
       DAY variable value
1  Tuesday     act1    67
2  Tuesday     act1    NA
3  Tuesday     act1    NA
4  Tuesday     act1    NA
5  Tuesday     act1    NA
6  Tuesday     act1    NA
7  Tuesday     act1    NA
8  Tuesday     act1    NA
9  Tuesday     act1    NA
10 Tuesday     act1    NA
```

To "spit out a new data frame with all processed rows", you can just process the subsetted data.frame however you like:

```
newDF <- transform( dataSet[duplicated(dataSet$variable),], DAY=sub("esd","foo",DAY) )
```

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Question is a bit ambiguous, but "split this data frame by picking out all the rows with duplicate column values" was what Iw as focusing on, since that's what he attempts with `unique`.  I'll change my answer to correctly answer his second piece, `spit out a new data frame with all processed rows`.

Comment: My concern was with `duplicated` not identifying all the rows in a group (one row per group is not there, and all the secondary rows are clumped together in a single group). Your edit addresses what I thought the point was. Removing down vote :)

Comment: Hm, upon re-reading I think you might be right.  "The rows" might mean just the 2+th row, but "all the rows" includes the initial row?  My ambiguous question dowsing rod is not very good today!  I'll delete if OP clarifies this isn't what he/she wanted.